# Keys for use during `completing-read`

Tags: key-bindings, completion, help

Am having difficulty finding information about the keys that can be used during `completing-read`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Completion Commands`